# Javascript regex to match html comments, excluding those inside <style> tags

Tags: javascript

I need to get html comments ( `<!-- -->` ) except for those inside  tags, which are used sometimes.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.test { font-size: 12px; }
-->
</style>
```

Getting html comments is quite easy with this regex:

```
/<!--[^>]*-->/gi
```

The issue is that i can't exclude those that are inside  tags. I tried:

```
(?!<style[^>]>)
```

but it still get the html comment. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't all comments technically inside tags? Do you mean comments inside childless tags? EDIT: See here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery/3671389#3671389

Comment: Why do your style tags have comments? They're unnecessary unless you like surfing the web with Netscape 1.0 or the like.