# Is it possible to select HTML comments using QueryPath?

Tags: html, html-parsing, querypath

I see this is possible using jQuery, but how can it be done in QueryPath?

[Selecting HTML Comments with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery)

If not, can anyone suggest an HTML parser that can select comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QueryPath comes with an extension called `QPXML` that has several add-on methods. One of these is `comment()`.

To use it, simply include it in your script:

```
include 'QueryPath/QueryPath.php';
include 'QueryPath/Extensions/QPXML.php';

htmlqp($html, $selector)->comment();
```

This will retrieve the first comment attached to the presently selected node(s).

If you have a really sophisticated set of comments all within the same nodes, you can do something like this:

```
$nodes = $qp->get();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
      if ($child->nodeType == XML_COMMENT_NODE) {
         // $child is a comment.
         print $child->textContent;
      }
   }
}
```

This is a little uglier, but it gives better access to cases where one element has a lot of comments in it.

Comment: Thanks! I should have just asked this on the QP mailing list way back when I needed it, luckily I found a workaround. :)

Comment: I had to do `\QueryPath::enable('\QueryPath\Extension\QPXML');` to get QPXML to work.

Answer (score 0):

To get ALL comments of HTML page via querypath :

```
    function  getAllComments($node) {
        if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
            foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
                $this->getAllComments($child);
                if ($child->nodeType == XML_COMMENT_NODE) {
                    echo  $child->textContent;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    $html = $qp->get() ;
    getAllComments($html[0]);
```