# QueryPath: Contains Selector

Tags: php, selector, querypath

QueryPath is giving me a hard time with the Contains selector in the code below. Everything I'm seeing looks to be correct.

```
$qp       = htmlqp($url, 'body');
$parent_table = $qp->branch()->find('table')->eq(0);

$listings    = $parent_table->branch()->find('table.text')->eq(0);
$rows        = $listings->branch()->find('tr:contains(<!--select_this-->)');
```

Here's my HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <table class="text">
            <tr>...</tr>
            <tr>
                <!---select_this-->
            </tr>
            .......
```

Comment: Does this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10712325/161179  help ?

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like it would solve the problem. I would prefer not to have to enable an extension to do something Querypath should do by default though.