# Select divs between html comments in lxml

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, xpath

This is my html file

```
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <!--Comment1-->
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <!--Comment2-->
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

and I want to select divs between Comment 1 and Comment 2

With this xPath = "/div/comment()" I can select `<!--Comment1--><!--Comment2-->`

But I want to select this

```
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
```

Comment: I just changed your divs, because you had them `<div><div/>` so if you have tried something and it aint worked double check that first.

Comment: here is an article, with a plugin, http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jQuery-Comments-Plug-in-To-Access-HTML-Comments-For-DOM-Templating.htm but not sure how it works,

Comment: here is another answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks for changing the divs I have just write manually so they are wrong. Actually It's a really big file!!

Comment: I'm trying to do it with lxml (python) not javascript! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 7):

```
//*[preceding-sibling::comment() and following-sibling::comment()]
```

Or stricter version:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::comment()[. = 'Comment1'] 
    and following-sibling::comment()[. = 'Comment2']]
```

Answer (score 1):

**In XPath 1.0 one can use the general (Kayessian) method for intersection** of two node-sets `$ns1` and `$ns2`:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

When we replace `$ns1` and `$ns2` with their specific selecting expressions for this particular case, we get:

```
/*/comment()[1]/following-sibling::div
            [count(. | /*/comment()[2]/preceding-sibling::div)
            =
             count(/*/comment()[2]/preceding-sibling::div)
            ]
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/comment()[1]/following-sibling::div
            [count(. | /*/comment()[2]/preceding-sibling::div)
            =
             count(/*/comment()[2]/preceding-sibling::div)
            ]
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <!--Comment1-->
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <!--Comment2-->
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

**The exact wanted nodes are selected and output**:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

**In XPath 2.0** one uses the `intersect` operator:

```
  /*/comment()[1]/following-sibling::div
intersect
 /*/comment()[2]/preceding-sibling::div
```