# How to capture commented HTML with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know if it is possible to capture a commented remark using JavaScript.

The remark will look like this on the soruce code:

```
<div id='ContainerId'>
<!-- NON IDEAL REASON: 90 min time window depart arrive -->
<b>1,107.45 GBP</b><br />
<!--LLF: 1107.45 -->
</div>
```

I need to save that value (in this case 1107.45) inside a variable.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
var LLF = jQuery("contains('LLF')");
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: There's an article about it here:
[jQuery Comments() Plug-in To Access HTML Comments For DOM Templating](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jQuery-Comments-Plug-in-To-Access-HTML-Comments-For-DOM-Templating.htm)

Comment: Check out the following post, it may give you a head-start: [Selecting HTML Comments with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery)

Comment: Are you generating the comment in your server side code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting HTML Comments with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery)

Comment: @bygrace Yes, this is generated on the server side.

Comment: Ok, it would probably be better if you just store it in a javascript variable then. I don't know what server-side language you are using but you could do something like `var LLF = '<%= LLF %>';` (for .NET) or `var LLF = '<?= LLF %>';` (for php)

Comment: If you are going for storing data in context of something on your page then you should look into useing the `data-*` attribute (http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Comment: Is the same content you're targeting actually going to be in the `<b>` element as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#ContainerId').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 8 // Comment node
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kUd4y/)

**And the full code:**

```
var comment = $('#ContainerId').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 8 // Comment node
})[0].nodeValue;

console.log(comment.match(/\d+\.\d+/g));​​​​​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kUd4y/)

Comment: This is what I am looking for, thank you.
Nevertheless, I realized that I have other commented lines under the same DIV, so it's capturing the first line instead of the desired one. How could I filter the node value?
Edit: I have updated the source code to reflect the code in place.

Comment: Sorry for my lame comment, just realized this: [0].nodeValue;