# Is there a DOM API for querying comment nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a document with a debugging comment in it that looks like this:

```
<!--SERVER_TRACE {...}-->
```

Is there a way to query the DOM to access this node? I am looking for a vanilla JavaScript solution, without the aid of any libraries.

My first thought was to depth first search the DOM and compare nodes found against the node type value for comments, `Node.COMMENT_NODE`. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Perhapes this helps:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType
But I haven't tested it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting HTML Comments with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery)

Comment: Wow, I was **sure** I knew that comment nodes were stripped. But not as far as I can tell: http://jsbin.com/ivufav/1/edit Tried it on Firefox, Chrome, and even IE7. They all had a node with `nodeType == 8` in the target, thus, didn't strip comments.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: Not a duplicate, as that question specifies the `jquery` tag, this one doesn't. It explicitly asks for a DOM API, not a library. (And the OP further clarified in the comment on an answer that he doesn't want to use jQuery.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Point made, I've put a pure JS implementation on. Also, he explicitely asks for a *way to query the DOM* - not an API. `childNode` recursion has never *not* been a way to access the DOM. Anyway - the OP has the only way of doing so. Case closed?

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's the `TreeWalker` APIs:

```
var tw = document.createTreeWalker(document, NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT, null, null),
    comment;
while (comment = tw.nextNode()) {
    // ...
}
```

This isn't supported by IE8 and lower.

T.J. in the comments provided a [link to the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/traversal.html). I kind of always use just TreeWalkers, but in your case a `NodeIterator` is fine too.

Comment: +1 Wow, and they're not even new: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/traversal.html What's support like (other than <IE8)? A [quick test](http://jsbin.com/ivufav/3) shows me that Chrome and Firefox both have it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Uh, never done extensive testings, but Chrome, Firefox and Opera all support it. I guess you can find it in mobile browsers too. Anyway, I've even coded a polyfill for those browsers that don't support it.

Comment: Here is my previous JSFiddle updated to use the `document.createTreeWalker()` : http://jsfiddle.net/JCDnh/3/ much smaller and easier to read, technically the same steps, but possibly faster if the JavaScript engine is leveraging native code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: It's existed for ever in Mozilla and a very long time in WebKit and Opera: I've been using it for many years. Apart from IE <= 8, support is universal, AFAIK (I haven't tested all the mobile browsers).

Comment: @TimDown: Cool, thanks! Too bad about IE8, I think we're going to be stuck with it for a while... But very, very useful thing to have in the back pocket.

Answer (score 9):

The `nodeType` core property allows you to differentiate between types of nodes. In this particular case, 8 represents comments. As they have no selector, you'll need to loop through their parent to get them (which sucks, I know). The following code filters them out for you:

```
$("*").contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE;
})
```

And my own jQuery-less version, because some people don't have it:

```
function getAllComments() {
    var t = [],
        recurse = function (elem) {
            if (elem.nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
                t.push(elem);
            };
            if (elem.childNodes && elem.childNodes.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    recurse(elem.childNodes[i]);
                };
            };
        };
    recurse(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]);
    return t;
};
```

If you'd like to search on a specific node, re-bind the `document.getElementsByTagName` call to a variable of your choosing.

**Edit**: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JCDnh/) to demonstrate the use, done by [Jason Sperske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16959/jason-sperske)!

Comment: And where does the OP say he's using jQuery?

Comment: Previous comment is correct, I don't want a jQuery solution. Edit: this means that this question is _not_ a duplicate of "Selecting HTML Comments with jQuery".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: where does the OP *not* say? Nevertheless, I've added a pure JS implementation.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: The absense of the `jquery` tag is, itself, sufficient, and the specificity of saying "a DOM API" makes it perfectly clear. Don't answer non-jQuery questions with jQuery-specific answers. (And of course, as of your update, now you haven't -- you've given an actual answer.)

Comment: A JSFiddle demo of the (very impressive) non jQuery approach: http://jsfiddle.net/JCDnh/

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted. It wasn't downvoted before the non-jQuery option was added (which might have been reasonable), and is certainly "useful" now the non-jQuery version has been added. There are a couple of issues with the code (extraneous semicolons and using `childNodes[i]` instead of using `firstChild` / `nextSibling`), but nothing remotely downvote-worthy.

Comment: The OP asks for an easier way than traversing the DOM and comparing the `nodeType`. This answer pretty much just regurgitated that. Nicely done, but not what was asked.

Comment: Because that question totally wasn't edited 6 hours after the fact to add the nodeType idea. Oh wait.