# How to leave an invisble marker in DOM so that later I can fill it with elements?

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom

Imagine a situation where I would like to put rows in a table dynamically:

```
<table>

  <tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th>
  <div class="rowsGoHere"></div>

</table>
```

The problem with this code is that Chrome, for instance, considers `<div>` inside a `<table>` to be illegal, and the resulting page code I see in inspector is the following:

```
<div class="rowsGoHere"></div>
<table>
  <tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th>
</table>
```

So Chrome automatically puts this div above the table. Now the question is, how do I avoid this situation? Is it possible to use something other than this `<div>` which I can later reference to insert elements into or after it? I should also point out the requirement that this element should be generic: I can't just use `<tr class="rowsGoHere">`.

This is a strictly html validity question, please do not recommend any jQuery code or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use tbody to append the new rows

```
<table>
   <thead>
   <tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <!--rowsGoHere-->
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, as I pointed out - it should be a generic element (it's a requirement). But your answer gave me an idea: can I use a comment `<!--rowsGoHere-->`? Is it a recognizable DOM member? Can I insert after or before it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'generic element'? Instead of <div class="rowsGoHere"></div> you can have <tbody class="rowsGoHere"></tbody>

Comment: What I mean is: I need one element that I can use both inside and outside the `<table>` tag.

Comment: Oh i see. That's gonna be tricky then. Your idea of using the HTML comment to append/prepend rows could work. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578784/insert-html-block-after-a-specific-html-comment

Comment: Yeah, I've tested it. It actually works. Thanks for helping me find this out.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up doing this:

```
<table>

  <tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th>
  <!--rowsGoHere-->

</table>
```

I could then identify this comment as a DOM element and insert what I need before it with `insertBefore()`. This approach has the advantage of being completely valid no matter which html elements it is used with (I can use it both with `<table>` as well as within `<div>` or `<ul>`).