# Find <td> contains value with quotes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is my HTML

```
<td class="ms-formbody" vAlign="top">
   <!--  FieldName="BP number"
             FieldInternalName="BP_x0020_number"
             FieldType="SPFieldText"
           -->
</td>
```

Now I want a selector thar find the `td` that contains a value like this: `FieldInternalName="BP_x0020_number"`

I am trying this... but it is not working

```
$( 'td:contains( "FieldInternalName="BP_x0020_number"" )' );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the actual content of your table cell contained within an HTML comment?

Comment: yes man... it is a table... and I cant modify the HTML

Comment: Escape the internal quotes?

Comment: @Benno Zeeman: Yes, but `contains` only works on text content (not comments)

Comment: Try this `$( 'td:contains( "FieldInternalName=\'BP_x0020_number\'" )' );`

Comment: This Question maybe help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you needed to escape your inner double-quotes (as you had quotes within quotes within quotes), but the main thing is to use a filter based on the HTML content (`contains` only looks at the text content for a string match):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ln92dv9/2/

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).html().indexOf("FieldInternalName=\"BP_x0020_number\"") > 0;
});
```

You can just use single quotes in this format (no escaping needed):

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).html().indexOf('FieldInternalName="BP_x0020_number"') > 0;
});
```