# jQuery insert html after comment tag

Tags: jquery, html, append, comments, insertafter

How do insert html after `<!-- example comment -->` in head document. For example I want to append css in head section with jquery after specific comment tag.

```
$('<link>', {
    rel: 'stylesheet',
     href: url
 }).appendTo($("<!-- Related css to this page -->"));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code from [selecting html comments with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3671389/295783)

```
var url ="bla.css";
$(function() {
  $("head").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 8;
  }).each(function(i, e) {
    if ($.trim(e.nodeValue) == "Related css to this page") {
      $('<link>', {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: url
      }).insertAfter(e);
      return false; // stop immediately - remove if f.ex. url is an array of css
    }
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE (which is using body since head is inserted by JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/u1phxLj1/)