# jQuery insert an element after a comment tag

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert `<br/><br/>` after the comment tag `<!-- pagebreak -->` but I'm not sure how to achieve this? my code so far:

html:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  some content
  <!-- pagebreak -->
  some more content
  <!-- pagebreak -->
  some more content
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( ".tab-content" )
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 8;}
  .each().after( "<br/><br/>" ).end());
```

Can anyone advise on how can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: have a look at this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

You were close. You don't need the `each`.

```js
$(".tab-content").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 8;
}).after("<br><br>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
  some content
  <!-- pagebreak -->
  some more content
  <!-- pagebreak -->
  some more content
</div>
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  some content
  <!-- pagebreak --><br><br>
  some more content
  <!-- pagebreak --><br><br>
  some more content
</div>
```