# How to access the comments present in the DOM using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to access the breadcrumbs that are commented out in the DOM. The code is something like this:

```
<div id = wrapper>
  <!--
      <ul class = "breadcrumbs">
           <li>Bcrumb1</li>
           <li>Bcrumb2</li>
      </ul> -->
    </div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why have you commented them out if you need them , did you try using display:none instead..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery