# how to get last comment in dynamically changed html with js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to find and alter the last comment node in a page (which will change periodically).

something like

```
<!-- first comment -->
<!-- second comment -->
<!-- third comment -->
<something></something>
```

the element following the last comment will always be "something", maybe there's a way to just grab the node before "something"?  having a hard time unpacking how dealing with nodes works

edit:  i've found answers about finding *all* the comment nodes but can't figure out how to select only the *last* one.  an additional hazard is that this is a weird project where i need to specifically use custom elements without ids or classes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting HTML comments with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery)

Comment: Can you improve your html markup with the comments structure?

Comment: @TylerRoper this is for a weird project with special crazy rules so i'm trying to avoid plugins though that looks like a good way.  i'm currently using the "return this.nodeType == 8;" technique in other parts of my code but can't figure out how to use that to select only the last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting, and I'm not sure if this is the best method, but if you can count on it **always** being before a certain DOM element, then you could start at that element and work backwards until you find the first comment. See this code as an example.

```js
let something = document.getElementsByTagName("something")[0]
let currentNode = something

// 8 is the node type for a comment
while (currentNode !== null && currentNode.nodeType !== 8) {
  currentNode = currentNode.previousSibling
}

console.log(currentNode.data)
```

```html
<!-- first comment -->
<!-- second comment -->
<!-- third comment -->
<something></something>
```

Comment: ooh this is very close!!  but i'm doing a weird project where i can't use ids just dom elements like <something></something> and i can't figure out how to alter this code to work that way.  ideas?

Comment: Well, if you have to use "something" you can select by tag name, and then get the first element. I updated my answer.

Comment: YES this is perfect thank you!!  i'm new to pure js and didn't know about selecting by tag names, that's great!