# Scraping HTML Comments using jQuery / CheerioJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, cheerio

I have this snippet of HTML code here: https://pastebin.com/wbQwys8R
My goal is to parse the HTML comments so I can put them in a dictionary. This snippet of code here

```
    $("body").find("div.cl-entry").each((currIndex, currElement) => {
        /* Get the comments from each run */
    })
```

Allows me to find all the HTML that gives me that small snippet of HTML code (the pastebin link) above but how do I parse the HTML comments themselves?

Comment: check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the `.children` property of the div will allow you to iterate through children *including comments* with Cheerio. For example:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(`
<div class='cl-info'>
  <!-- updated=Saturday, 13-Mar-2021 06:46:41 GMT -->
  <!-- id=985dad7f1491 -->
  <!-- status=active -->
  <!-- offline=no -->
  <!-- name=0-30 Kiwi-SDR Flornes, Norway LB8PI -->
  <!-- sdr_hw=KiwiSDR v1.438 ⁣  DRM ⁣ -->
</div>`);
for (const child of $('.cl-info')[0].children) {
    if (child.type === 'comment') {
        console.log(child.data);
    }
}
```

results in the following being logged:

```
 updated=Saturday, 13-Mar-2021 06:46:41 GMT 
 id=985dad7f1491
 status=active
 offline=no
 name=0-30 Kiwi-SDR Flornes, Norway LB8PI 
 sdr_hw=KiwiSDR v1.438 ⁣ � DRM ⁣
```